# How to convert given string to a valid datetime of the server?

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

I am trying to convert a given string which comes from a webservice to datetime. It works on local machine but when I try it from remote server, it gives an error like

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.".

Please see the code in below and recommend a general solution for this problem.

```
DateTime test = DateTime.ParseExact(XmlStringHelper.GetTagValue(result, "date"), "ddMMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that, value of the date parameter comes as "13FEB".

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: If your `XmlStringHelper.GetTagValue(result, "date")` _really_ returns `"13FEB"`, you code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the server is probably running with different culture as you local machine. The result from XmlStringHelper.GetTagValue(result, "date") is probably in an other formatting. Comapare the culture settings and the result of the XmlStringHelper.GetTagValue(result, "date") on both machines.

Comment: Is it possible to make it compatible for every server culture?

Comment: You must first be sure of the cause of your problem before  changing stuff. You can set the culture in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the date string from the web-service is localized.

Thus, you will have to adopt to the culture of the web-service, like:

```
DateTime test = DateTime.ParseExact(XmlStringHelper.GetTagValue(result, "date"), "ddMMM",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.*RemoteServerCulture*);
```